# I can't get this Javascript to work when it's echoed by PHP

Tags: php

The following javascript Code is provided by eBay Partnernetwork and it works well in a HTML file, but when I try to `echo()` it in a PHP script, it's not parsed correctly.

Here's the code:

```
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://adn.ebay.com/files/js/min/jquery-1.6.2-min.js'></script>
 <script type='text/javascript' src='http://adn.ebay.com/files/js/min/ebay_activeContent-min.js'></script>
 <script charset='utf-8' type='text/javascript'>
 document.write("\x3Cscript type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8' src='http://adn.ebay.com/cb?programId=11&campId=XXX&toolId=10026&keyword=Huawei+MediaPad+3G&sortBy=4&width=180&height=60&font=1&textColor=333366&linkColor=333333&arrowColor=FF9900&color1=6599FF&color2=[COLORTWO]&format=ImageLink&contentType=TEXT_AND_IMAGE&enableSearch=y&usePopularSearches=n&freeShipping=n&topRatedSeller=n&itemsWithPayPal=n&descriptionSearch=n&showKwCatLink=n&excludeCatId=&excludeKeyword=&catId=171485&disWithin=200&ctx=n&autoscroll=n&title=Odys+Noon&flashEnabled=' + isFlashEnabled + '&pageTitle=' + _epn__pageTitle + '&cachebuster=' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000 ))'>\x3C/script>" );
 </script>
```

I think there's a problem with the quotes at `document.write("...");` but whatever I try, it doesn't work. I escaped them and also replaced them with hex code, but with no success.

Comment: (a) What's the PHP code you're using? (b) What's the output (view source in the browser)?

Comment: It is only HTML/Javascript. Why do you need echo?!

Comment: Make sure - your PHP script have a right encoding(utf8)? May be your problem in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried `document.write("<scr"+"ipt src=blahblahblah></scr"+"ipt>");`

Comment: I don't know why.. but this works :D Strange world, do you got an explanation?
Btw.. I had to escape the quotes additionally, to get it to work. document.write(\"<scr\"+\"ipt src=blahblahblah></scr\"+\"ipt>\");
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Yeah...it's weird. It's a security issue with browsers not wanting to allow people to write scripts to the page. I assume you were trying to accomplish something similar with the encoded < but I'd imagine browsers are smart enough to figure that out. By splitting up the word script into two separate strings, It tricks the browser to letting you write the script

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
    $str = <<<EOF
 //your script here --->(1)
EOF;
    echo $str;
?>
```

Note : the     EOF; alignment is  important(leftmost), try to type this in a better ide or atleast Notepad++!

**update:**

> Note : No more escaping inside  --->(1) like in your script

Comment: doesn't work, but thanks anyway!

Comment: problem is that you dont want to escape within document.write("") if you are echoing.....try it in my script (dont put escaped item inside it ,i thought you will do it early, just document.write("<script src='popy'></script>"); is enough ! Thanks

Comment: I tried it, but also without escaping it still doesn't work. But the solution from Brad works fine. Thank you anyway!